# From Roman cubits to meters

Tags: geometry

Assuming that $a=50$ [Roman cubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Roman_units_of_measurement) $(1 cubit =44$cm), and I want to find the surface of this square. I do: **a*a=s**. ($50$ cubits $\times$ $50$ cubits= $2500$ cubits = **$1100$ meters**). But if I calculate how many cubits in $50$ meters I get different results.

$50
 \times 0.44$cm$=22$m $  \gt 22$m $ \times $ $22$m= **484 meters** (another way: $50$cu $\times$ $44$cm $\times$ $50$cu $\times$ $44$cm=$484$m$^2$). 
Now, I'm sure the last result is the correct one, but I don't understand why, because at the moment my logic says that the amount of the cubits ($2500$) should be equal to the amounts of cubits in meters ($1100$). But I see different results, then I'm wondering where's my mistake in the understanding?

[image]

Comment: $\text {cubit} \times \text {cubit} \ne \text {cubit}$. It is $(\text {cubit})^2$

Comment: This means that we have first to convert $\text {cubit}$ into $\text {cm}$ and then multiply to get ${\text {cm}}^2$.

Comment: So we cannot say that 50cubit *50 cubits are 2500 cubits?

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent 50 cubit * 50 cubit = 2500 cubits^2, like 50m area * 50m area is 2500m^2 not just meters otherwise that is just a flat ruler

Comment: Of coures $50 \times 50 = 2500$. The issue is that the ratio to convert ${\text {cubit}}^2$ to ${\text {cm}}^2$ is **not**  $44$ but is $44 \times 44$.

Comment: And they are **not** $\text {cubit}$ but ${\text {cubit}}^2$

Comment: It was a typo. I edited it. Thank you.

Comment: The same mistake for meters; an area has ${\text {meter}}^2$ as unit of measure

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mauro said in the comment, when you are multiplying $50 \times 50$ cubits the unit is $(cubits)^2$, so we cannot just multiply by $0.44$ to get $1100$, actually we have to do $2500 \times 0.44^2 =484$ which confirms your other result!

Try converting between $m^2 \rightarrow cm^2$ you have to square the usual factor in which you go from $m \rightarrow cm$

Comment: @Olly, While the previous answer I understood, this one I didn't. We all agree that the surface of 50*44cm / 50*44cm square is **484** meter (50*44*50*44). Isn't it? I tried the new way you wrote and didn't reach this result.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent yes I think we were right the first time, $0.1936$ physically cannot make sense, its probably easier thinking about it buy converting each length first then finding the area!

Comment: My mistake, I read the original post as stating the conversion is that 50 cubits is equivalent to 44 centimetres.

Comment: Honestly, it's **my** mistake that misled you. I'll correct it immediately.

Comment: Well, part of answering questions on a Stack Exchange site is that you have to do your homework. In this case, that meant clicking the link you provided and looking up "cubit"! I failed to do that! :)